# Quoting within tags in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, i'm working on views for my little project. Every day I make things like this:

```
<li <%= 'class="'+item.status.caption+'"' if %w{ sold, absent }.include?(item.status.caption) %> >
```

Recently, I found a proper String method in Ruby API, called **quote**. 
I wrote this:

```
<li <%= 'class='+item.status.caption.quote if %w{ sold, absent }.include?(item.status.caption) %> >
```

but application dropped an error, saying it does not recognize the method. So, is there a proper method to do such usual quotation (or, even, 'somethination' with a custom symbol/string :P )? Anything like 'surround_with' or something? Didn't found a clue in Rail API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create a pretty trivial helper, for example:

```
  def quoted_class(val)
    "class='#{val}'"
  end
```

Then you'd use it in your example like so:

```
<li <%= quoted_class(item.status.caption) if %w{s,abs}.include?(item.status.caption) %>>
```

Comment: Hmm, I believe that will do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

That's way too much logic inside a view, and you're not using the helpers Rails gives you.  Make a method in your **foo_helper.rb** file in `app/helpers` (where 'foo' is your controller name):

```
def display_item(item)
  case item.status.caption
    when /sold/ then class = 'sold'
    when /absent/ then class = 'absent'
    else class = nil  # You could add more cases here as needed
  end
  content_tag :li, item.name, :class => class  # Or whatever you want shown
end
```

Then, in your view, you can call `<%= display_item(item) %>` instead of all that embedded `if` gibberish.

(Oh, and this wasn't your question, but as an additional exercise, also think about how to reduce that `item.status.caption` chaining, either with methods like `item.sold?` and `item.absent?` or by turning `status` into something you can test directly.  Google on "Law of Demeter" to find out why this is a good idea.)

Comment: Hmm, thanx. I'm convinced that for now my views are pretty dirty, and certainty was going to do something about that. Thanks for additional pushing :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use content_tag? You don't say what you are displaying within the li, but you could do something like:

`<%= content_tag :li, "your list content", ({:class => item.status.caption} if %w{ sold absent }.include?(item.status.caption)) %>`

By the way, I don't think you want the comma in your %w string, unless you really want to match against "sold," (with a comma) or "absent".

Comment: Yeah, already deleted that come, thanks ) And surely thanks for content_tag, that's probably the most convenient way

Answer (score 0):

To use quotes, I'd do something like this:

```
"This is '#{string_inside_quotes}'."
```

Or

```
"This is \"#{string_inside_quotes}\"."
```

though it's not quite clear to me what you mean in your original example.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
<li class="<%= item.status.caption if %w{ sold, absent }.include?(item.status.caption) %>">
```

as an empty class attribute is like no class attribute?

If you don't want to escape your quotes there is also another way to quote in ruby:

```
<li <%= %q(class="#{item.status.caption}") if %w{ sold, absent }.include?(item.status.caption) %>>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've done that in early stages. But don't much like those empty class= attributes, left on page.

Comment: It's a way to quote strings in Ruby. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Alternate_quotes